# What is the cursor object in sqlite databases in python?

Tags: python, database, sqlite, cursor

I worked with a sqlite databases in python then After databse connect as fllow **db=sqlite3.connect("database.sqlite")** we use **db.cursor()**. what is this cursor object ? Is it common in any DBMS ? Please explain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cursors are indeed extremely common in all sorts of databases; the "run along" (that's what the root "cursor" means in Latin: "runner") results from queries (which in Python access to relational DB,s in particular, you execute on the cursor themselves), yielding them a little at a time, or all at once, at your choice.

A `sqlite3.Cursor` instance has a few more methods and attributes, beyond those that other cursor objects in Python interfaces to DBs generally offer.  However, you don't have to use them, and you often can keep better portability of your code by sticking closer to the general Python "DB API" you can study starting from https://wiki.python.org/moin/DatabaseProgramming/ and links therefrom.

Comment: Can you explain more?

Comment: @user3152250 not really: I can answer questions, you've asked two, I answered them.  Your very generic request to "explain" -- as you may see from the two votes to close, neither yet mine -- is too broad and vague -- explain *what*?  The whole theory of relational databases?  The tiny differences between a Python cursor for MySql and one for sqlite3?  Between the former macrocosm, and the latter microcosm, it's obviously too vast a chasm for me to guess exactly what you already know vs what you have questions on -- so **ask** those questions, already!